# How to display a row number using Struts <logic:iterate>

Tags: jsp, struts, struts-1, struts-tags

I have an `ArrayList` and I'mam using Struts 1 `<logic:iterate>` to iterate and display records in the table. Since the list size is bigger now I need to the display the row number in the first column. How to achieve this?

### Tried option:1

```
 <% long count = 1;%>
 <logic:iterate id="iter" name="empForm" property="empList"  >
 <tr>  <td> <%= count++ %>  <td>  </tr>
```

Working but scriptlet should not be used.

### Tried option:2

```
<logic:iterate id="iter" name="empForm" property="empList" indexId="index" >

 <tr>  <td> <bean:write name="index"/> <td>  </tr>
```

**Problem:**  working index starts like 0,1,2 that needs to be as 1,2,3

How to show as 1,2,3 instead of 0,1,2?

Comment: <c:out value="${index + 1}"/>

Answer (score 1):

You're using `logic:iterate`, which is explicitely documented as "should not be used anymore", by a framework (Struts 1) that is itself deprecated and officially abandoned for several years. Stop using Struts 1, really.

And, in the meantime, at least learn the [JSP EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) and [the JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info). They exist for more that 10 years:

```
<c:forEach var="employee" varStatus="loopStatus" values="${empForm.empList}">
  <tr>
    <td>${loopStatus.index + 1}<td>
    <td><c:out value="${employee.name}"/></td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
<bean:write name="index"/>
```

you can use

```
<c:out value="${index + 1}"/>
```